# Can I define Express routes in a child process?

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

So I run a bunch of a little chatbots written in node, nothing too exciting. However, I recently decided to give them their own little web page to display information in a graphical manner. To do this, I figured I'd just run express.

However, I'm running my bots with a wrapper file that starts each chatbot as a child process. Which makes using express a little tricky. Currently I'm starting the express server in the `wrapper.js` file like so:

```
var express = require("express");  
var web = express();  
web.listen(3001);
```

And then in the child processes, I'm doing this:

```
var express = require("express");
var web = express();
web.get("/urlforbot",function (req,res) {
   res.send("Working!"); 
});
```

However, when I navigate to `:3001/urlforbot`, I get `Cannot GET /urlforbot`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

**Edit**: This is my complete wrapper file: http://snippi.com/s/3vn56m2

**Edit 2**: This is what I'm doing now. I'm hosting each bot on it's own port, and storing that information in the configs. This is the code I'm using, and it appears to be working:

```
web.get("/"+cfg.route, function (req,res) { // forward the data
   res.redirect('http://url.com:'+cfg.port+"/"+cfg.route);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your bots run as separate processes (any particular reason?), you have to treat each one as having to implement their own HTTP server with Express:

```
var express = require("express");
var web = express();
web.get("/urlforbot",function (req,res) {
   res.send("Working!"); 
});
web.listen(UNIQUE_PORT_NUMBER);
```

Each bot process needs to listen on a unique port number, it can't be shared.

Next, you need to map requests coming in on port 3001 in the 'master' process to the correct child process' Express server.

`node-http-proxy` has a useful option called a [`ProxyTable`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxy-requests-using-a-proxytable) with which to create such a mapping, but it requires the master process to know what the endpoint (`/urlforbot` in your terms) for each bot is. It also requires that the master knows on which port the bots are listening.

**EDIT:** alternatively, you can use [`child_process.fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to fork a new process for each of your bots, and communicate between them and the master process (port numbers and such, or even all the data required to generate the `/urlforbot` pages) using the comm channel that Node provides, but that still sounds like an overly complex setup.

Wouldn't it be possible to create a `Bot` class instead? You'd instantiate the class for each bot you want to run, and that instance loads its specific configuration and adds its routes to the Express server. All from the same process.

Comment: They run as seperate processes because they all use the same javascript files. I differentiate them with unique config files. I used to run them as individual node processes, actually, but running them as child processes saves on memory use and is easier to manage in the long run. So my only option is to set up a unique webserver? And I actaully think that the proxy would work, I could just add the port and route into the process. `bots = { 'bot1':{'port':'x','url':'x' }`. That actually might be difficult, as I dynamically generate the url in the bot file. And I'd have to increment the ports..

Comment: In my edit, I added a link to the entirety of the code of my wrapper, the file that starts the bots. I'm already using child.fork to spawn them. I suppose I could use message passing to define routes, but I really just wanted to use the wrapper to start each bot at once. And I'm also not very good with classes. This is actually going to be my first project where I use constructors, so...